# How to use modal dialog with Angular and VMware Clarity?

Tags: angular, dialog, modal-dialog, vmware-clarity

I need to display a modal dialog control with a question and yes/no buttons, wait for the user's choice, then run some code to perform the selected action.

The VMWare Clarity documentation is very clear about the markup inside the dialog, but it does not talk about how to show or hide it.

I'd love a complete example, thank you.

Comment: .... I mean reusable solution, something like dialog service, not fixed dialog control in every component - this is usable in small applications.

Comment: I think an issue is already filed for this: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/1364. Is this what you are looking for? If yes, you should subscribe to that for more updates from the Clarity team.

Comment: Thank for link - that discussion is about dialog service, but without solution.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean to say that you want to act on an input user provided in the dialog? You can use `ngModel`. Please describe in detail what you are looking for.

Comment: Need somethig like this, for angular 4: (sorry for bad formatting, I use `` but it not work here)


`
dialogservice.confirm("Are you sure?", {title : "Dialog title"})
          .then(function(p) { code for success },
                function(p) { code for fail }
          );
`

As you see, everything is at one place and simple.

Comment: Still not clear?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are describing a situation where you want to confirm an action (like confirm you wish to delete an item), and if so you should review the code found here. You can follow the methods it calls to see the logic.

https://github.com/gnomeontherun/clarity-workshop/blob/master/src/app/budget/budget/budget.component.html#L56

This is a delete button that calls a method, which then opens a modal dialog. The user then confirms or cancels, and then if they confirm it calls the API to actually delete.

If you'd like to make your own service to control the modal, you can follow the example I have for an alert service and alert component (but change it to a modal). https://github.com/angular-in-action/portfolio/tree/master/src/app/alert

Comment: Thank for answer. Yes, I need to wait for user response and then do some action. Your example in link above use create <clr-modal> for every dialog in every component where dialog is needed - modal dialogs are part of component. There are some dialog service in npm sources, but unfortunately is not maintained for angular 4/5.

Comment: Clarity modals are declarative, and do not have a service currently. It is a feature request here https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/1364 if you'd like to submit more details about your expectations.

Comment: Also you could have one 'global' modal, and create your own service to control when it appears and what it displays.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the user clicks on a "Delete order" button, and you want to display a modal dialog with "Are you sure?" and "Cancel" and "Delete" buttons.

Jeremy's example above is great. Here is a minimal implementation:

In `order.component.ts`:

```
isModalVisible = false;

deleteOrder() {
  ...
}
```

In `order.component.html`:

```
<div>
  ...
  <button (click)="isModalVisible = true">Delete Order</button>
  ...
</div>

<clr-modal [(clrModalOpen)]="isModalVisible">
  <h3 class="modal-title">Delete order?</h3>
  <div class="modal-body">This cannot be undone.</div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn (click)="isModalVisible = false">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn (click)="deleteOrder()">Delete</button>
  </div>
</clr-modal>
```

Angular 6.1.9, Clarity 0.13.4